# Using | operator with Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, attributes

this is my setup:

```
public class MyEnums
{
    [Flags]
    public enum MyGroups
    {
        None = 0,
        Test1 = 1,
        Test2 = 2
    }
}


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class MyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly MyGroups _allowedGroups;

    public MyAttribute(MyGroups allowedGroups)
    {
        _allowedGroups = allowedGroups;
    }

    ...
}


[MyAttribute(MyGroups.Test1 | MyGroups.Test2)]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

I specifically do not understand what is happening in the **[MyAttribute(MyGroups.Test1 | MyGroups.Test2)]** part on the controller side.
Am I instantiating multiple attributes (?)"

```
[MyAttribute(MyGroups.Test1)]
[MyAttribute(MyGroups.Test2)]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is what's called a flag enum and it's "used whenever the enum represents a collection of possible values rather an a single value" from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8447/9363973) excellent Q&A. It basically allows you signal to a user that the values in the enum can appear in any grouping. The `AttributeUsage` is an excellent example. In your code it specifies that `MyAttribute` is valid on Classes and Methods

Comment: There’s only one attribute so there’s no instantiating multiple attributes

Comment: As MindSwipe has mentioned, you have only one attribute, but its value can be a mix of `MyGroups` enum. in your `[MyAttribute(MyGroups.Test1 | MyGroups.Test2)]` the value of `allowedGroups` would be 3 (both `MyGroups.Test1` and `MyGroups.Test2`)

Comment: Totally clear, thanks everyone! I thought it had to do with the attribute in my controller itself while instead it had to do with [Flag] attribute. Thanks again!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is the [bitwise OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-or-operator-) operator.

You are not defining 2 attributes, you are defining 1, and passing an enum that has the value `Test1` or `Test2`.

It might be clearer if you define your enum using binary literals:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyGroups
{
    None = 0b0000,  // 0000
    Test1 = 0b0001, // 0001
    Test2 = 0b0010  // 0010
}
```

When you do a bitwise OR, you check each binary digit, and the result is where 1 is present in either value (as opposed to bitwise AND, which requires both digits to be 1).

So `MyGroups.Test1 | MyGroups.Test2` is equivalent to:

```
  0001
| 0010
= 0011
```

When using this technique, it is important to use square numbers for the enum values to ensure that the bitwise operations do not result in a value that clashes with a single enum value. So if you were to extend your enum you should do the following:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyGroups
{
    None = 0b0000,  // 0000
    Test1 = 0b0001, // 0001
    Test2 = 0b0010, // 0010
    Test3 = 0b0100, // 0100
    Test4 = 0b1000  // 1000
}
```

Or using integer literals:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyGroups
{
    None = 0,
    Test1 = 1,
    Test2 = 2,
    Test3 = 4,
    Test4 = 8
}
```